# How javascript indexOf works differently with string and array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, indexof

I have both string and array of strings.

```
var strFruit = "Apple is good for health";  
var arrayFruit = ["Apple is good for health"]; 

var strResult = strFruit.indexOf("Apple"); //strResult shows 0  
var arrayResult =  arrayFruit.indexOf("Apple"); // arrayResult  shows -1
```

But if i use `arrayFruit.indexOf("Apple is good for health")` arrayResult shows 0.

And my Question is **why indexOf looks for exact match in Array element but not in string** and how both search differ?.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvnemcxk/)

**P.S**: Main reason to ask this question is i am unable to understand source code for `indexOf`.I can understand **what** it does(`indexOf`) with string and array.But im not sure **how** it is working with string and Array?([poly fills or source code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description)).

Answer (score 1):

When searching in array, `indexOf` tries to search for entire string. For example:

```
var arrayFruit = ["Apple", "is", "good", "for", "health"]; 
var arrayResult =  arrayFruit.indexOf("Apple"); // arrayResult will be 0
```

In you your case, you have only one item in the array i.e. string representing `"Apple is good for health"`. So `indexOf` tries to match `"Apple"` with it. Since:

```
"Apple is good for health" != "Apple"
```

you get `-1` as answer. Had you searched for entire string, it would give you `0`

```
var arrayResult =  arrayFruit.indexOf("Apple is good for health"); /arrayResult will be 0
```

Answer (score 1):

When using indexOf in a string, it searches the string for the argument that you passed it. On the other hand when using it on an array, it searches the array for that element.

String:

```
var myString = "Apple is good for health";
console.log("Apple is at", myString.indexOf("Apple"));
//Outputs "Apple is at 0"
```

Array:

```
var myArray = ["Apple is good for health", "Another sentence", "Sentence 3"];
console.log("Apple is good for health is element", myArray .indexOf("Apple is good for health"));
//Outputs "Apple is good for health is element 0"
console.log("Sentence 3 is at", myArray.indexOf("Sentence 3"));
//Outputs "Sentence 3 is at 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

`strFruit.indexOf("Apple")` searches for string `Apple` in `strFruit` but `arrayFruit.indexOf("Apple")` searches for an item in array with the value `Apple`

Answer (score 0):

In arrayFruit you have one object of string and for comparing it shoud match the same object for `result= 0`

In strFruit you have sequence of characters, it matches these sequence of charachters with indexOf

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke `indexOf` for `array` object it will compare full text with  each element , so in your case you are comparing a single word with full sentence ( which is the only element in array), which returns `-1`, and that is fine . But if you do like this,

```
var k = "Apple is good for health".split(" ");
var idx = k.indexOf("Apple"); // it will return 0
```